# Preferred package of grails spring security plugin classes

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.3

Suppose I want to use **Secured** annotation of grails spring security core 2.0 plugin, which package should I use: either **grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured** or **org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured**.

I'm using the former one but will there any problem if I use the latter one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are supported, [as described in the docs](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html#securedAnnotations).

The `grails.plugin` annotation is newer and has more features, such as letting your define security checks in closures. But the `org.springframework` annotation (which is part of Spring Security, not the plugin) is still supported; the newer one has the same config optons as the old one and adds some new ones.

Comment: Thank You Burt for clarification.